# Is it possible to have a central vertex in a graph with 2 or more components?

Tags: graph-theory

Everywhere I find the concept of central vertex, it do not say if it is a unique component only or it can have a set for each component in a graph.

Answer (score 1):

the definition of a central vertex does not make sense when the graph is not connected, although you can talk about central vertices within each component.